# changes in sounds in Indo-European languages

Tags: proto-indo-european, indo-european, sound-change

Forgive me if this question is too simple/repetitive/... as I'm not familiar with technical terms.

I'm looking for a good reference that's explained the changes in sounds in Indo-European daughter languages. For example 'P', 'V' and 'F' have interchangeably been used in different languages.

I was wondering what other sounds and in which languages this changes has occurred.

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for functional explanations? Most of that is kind of crazy speculation having to do with mountain air and savagery. Or are you looking for actual data, as in Brugman's Comparative Grammar (https://archive.org/details/ElementsComparativeGrammarIndo-germanicLanguages.brugmann.1888.5Volumes)?

Answer (score 1):

I always look into this one [Mallory, J.P. and Adams, D.Q., 2006. The oxford introduction to proto-indo-european and the proto-indo-european world. Oxford University Press on Demand.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199296685)

On page **464** there is a table with the sound correspondences in different major IE-language groups. There is a digital copy of that table (+ an addenda) here: [Basic sound correspondences between PIE and the major IE groups](http://www.palaeolexicon.com/Tools/PIEPhonology)

Comment: It's actually so handy. Thank you. But not exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you again

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani what are you looking for exactly? Your question is a little too generic. The answer provided by Midas looks quite informative to me